# Parsing Implicit Multiplication

Tags: python, parsing, parser-generator, lalr

I've been trying to set up a rather simple math parser, and it's been working fine. Only I can't figure out how to put in implied multiplication.

I've been using [`lark`](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark) as an lalr(1) parser.

Here's most of the grammar:

```
?start: expression

?expression: sub

?sub: plus ("-" plus)*
?plus: times ("+" times)*
?times: divide ("*" divide)*
?divide: power ("/" power)?
?power: unary ("^" unary)*

?unary: positive
      | negative
      | atom

?atom: "(" expression ")"
     | numeric 
     | symbol

positive: "+" unary
negative: "-" unary

?numeric: FLOAT
        | INT

?symbol: WORD

%import common.WORD
%import common.INT
%import common.FLOAT
%import common.WS_INLINE
%ignore WS_INLINE
```

How would I go about adding in and implicit times operator?

Making the times "*" operator optional works fine, except that addition/subtraction doesn't work because it's interpreted as unary positive/negative instead. `x - y` is interpreted as `x times -y`, but it should be `x sub y`.

Comment: You're not including variables in your grammar, so the only possible case of implied multiplication is when you have `(exp1)(exp2)`, right ?

Comment: @Niloct The symbols rule is for variables. Plus without parentheses too, I want `2 2` or `2 x y` to count as multiplication.

Comment: Ah symbols, indeed. But `2 2` isn't clear to be a multiplication imho.

Comment: I agree, I think it's sorta confusing if there's no symbols there. But I'm trying to have somewhat similar syntax to Mathematica, so having it would be nice.

Comment: I think you can't ignore whitespace and at the same time make it count as an operator.

Comment: That's some weird precedence you've got there, what with `+` having higher precedence than `-` and `/` having higher precedence than `*`.

Comment: Huh? Making the `'*"` optional works properly, except that there's a bunch of misinterpretations. `1 - 1` is interpreted as  `1 times negative 1` instead of `1 sub 1`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The parser I'm using has Terminal Priority, so it's the reverse.

Comment: @weakit: That's not what terminal priority does, and even if it was, the reverse precedence would still be weird. `+` and `-` should have equal precedence, as should `*` and `/`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I'm kinda new to parsing, but it seems to work properly, without the implicit multiplication. I'll try to edit to make them have equal precedence.