How to multiply two elements from mathematical formula without using an asterisk in Python?
I'm trying to make a program in Python that would make physics calculations easier. I've added some physical constants as variables and trying to make operations using them by inputting the formula via input() and calculating using eval(). The thing is, it requires an asterisk and I would like to find a workaround. Currently it only works on something like this: p=m*v and does not work on p=mv, while the latter is, as far as I know, more commonly used in textbooks etc.
Tried inputting a formula "ue", expected a result of 2.6604783878223602e-46
u=1.66054*10**(-27)
pi=3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169
c2=299792458**2
formula=input("Input formula: ")
answer=eval(formula)
print(answer)

and got an error:
    answer=eval(formula)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ue' is not defined


How should the program know that mv means "multiply m and v" and not a single value mv? Or that pi does not mean "multiply p and i"?

You need to define a grammar for the expressions the user is allowed to input and write a parser for it.

Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691981/parsing-implicit-multiplication

Don't use eval. The user can enter more than just the formula you imagine or expect the user to enter.

First of all do not use eval without making sure that the command is safe, since
eval("exit()")
Just exits the program, working just like the exec function.
But a program such as follows should make your goal possible:
from math import *
class Function():
    def recSpecialFuncs(func,string):
        match string:
            case "sin":
                return "sin"
            case "cos":
                return "cos"
            case _:
                return "?"

    def Parse(func,string):

        chrSeq = "";digest = ""
        for c,l in enumerate(list(string)):
            if l in func.vars:
                chrSeq += l
                n = "*" if len(chrSeq) >1 else ""
                val = func.recSpecialFuncs(chrSeq)
                if val=="?":
                    digest+=n+l
                elif len(chrSeq) > 1:
                    digest = digest[:(len(digest)+2-2*len(chrSeq)+1)]
                    digest += "$@"+val+"$"


            else:
                chrSeq = ""
                if l in func.b:
                    digest+=l
                elif l in func.operators:
                    if l == "^":
                        digest+="**"
                    else:
                        digest+=l
                elif l.isnumeric() or l == ".":
                    digest+=l
        func.digest= digest
        func.split = func.digest.split("$")

    def run(func,vals):
        st = ""

        for val in func.split:
            cp = val
            if len(val)>0 and val[0]!="@":
                for g in vals:
                    cp=cp.replace(g[0],str(g[1]))
            st+=cp



        return eval(st.replace("@",""))
    def __init__(func,string):
        super().__init__()
        func.b = list("()")
        func.operators=list("+-^*/")
        func.vars = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        func.Parse(string)


Take this example:
sine = Function("sin(x)")
print(sine.run([("x",0)]))

Output:
0.0

If you want some specific constant you can add them to the recSpecialFuncs switch, e.g:
case "pi":
   return "pi"

To use more than 1 variables pass more:
func = Function("mv^2/2")
print(func.run([("m",1),("v",2)]))

